# Make panel within split container appear protrude

Tags: winforms

I have a form in WinForm application. In this form I placed a split container (vertical). In the lower panel I placed another split container (horizontal). The right one has two pannels, one has the BorderStyle set to FixedSingle and the other None. It looks like this:

[image: Panel with FixedSingle BorderStyle]

I want it to look like this (as if the panel was part of the border of the split container):

[image]

Is there any easy way to accomplish this using different controls?

Comment: If you want this "easy" then simply write an event handler for the panel's Paint event.  Draw the beveled edges with the methods offered by e.Graphics, the ClientSize property tells you where to draw.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. That looks like the hard way but I guess I'll have to go through that path. Let's see if someone has another idea :)